# TFS Visual Studio. Download dll for all developer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

When I use TFS with my colleagues and I download DLL with NuGet Packages and Push project into TFS server my colleagues can't have the dll when they get project by TFS. 
They must download too the same DLL by NuGet.

**Is there a solution to have DLL download by one developer when all developer get project in TFS ?**

Comment: Why is this a concern? Managing packages with NuGet is a good practice.

Comment: It is best practice to NOT check nuget packages into TFS (or any version control).  The reason is that binaries take up a large amount of space in the repository and can bloat it.

Comment: If you're saying that they must use the "Restore nuget packages" for a solution after getting/updating it, why is this a bad thing? If you're referencing the dll files in some other way, please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

**Very bad practice, We don't recommend check NuGet packages into TFS**, just as mentioned by Daniel and Erik, it's better to manage packages with Nuget.

But if you still want to do that, you can check in the dll files to TFS manually. You need to check in the entire packages, dll files are excluded by default.

Right Click in Source Control Explorer > Add items to folder > Select the project packages (dll files) > Switch to **Excluded items** tab > Select the dll fiels > Include items > Finish > Check in the dll files.

Thus the packages (dll files) will be downloaded with the project when someone get project in TFS.

[image]